# Is there a good media center program with these specs?

Tags: media-player

I'm planning on turning an old laptop into a media center for our home. However, I need some pretty specific features:

- Netflix integration
- Hulu integration
- YouTube integration
- XBOX controller support (Using 360 Wireless for this project)
- Possibly Steam integration for gaming.
- Possibly a web browser.

I can run on any platform, but I'd prefer Windows or Ubuntu for this. Also, I want the media center to have true controller capabilities. This means it's not an emulated mouse. The controller can actually select things. If possible, I would like to be able to assign hotkeys so I can use my dPad and similar for play/pause, FF/Rewind, and volume. If absolutely necessary, I would be okay with scripting actions.

I would prefer free, but cheap (less than $30) would work as well. I am fine with plugins for an existing solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that a good choice for what you desire can be realized by using [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) for Windows. It's a full featured media center that supports many "add-ins" including hulu, netflix, etc. You don't need a keyboard or mouse to control it. There are many third party apps that allow you to control it from your phone or tablet.  Oh, did I mention it's free?

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning XBMC is available for Linix, too. It's even [in the repositories for Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/precise/video/xbmc) (in universe).

Answer (score 2):

## [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/)

<sup>(I'm not sure if this qualifies as a separate answer since it's also based on XBMC. Let me know please)</sup>

OpenELEC is a free and open source standalone linux distribution that boots directly into XBMC mentioned in [rrirower's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13580/6834) with no need for a parent OS. It can achieve much better performance with minimal system requirements, which would make it perfect for old devices. You can install further features as add-ons. All the following links are to their respective pages on the XBMC wiki:

- [Netflix](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:XBMC_Flicks_-_Netflix_for_XBMC)
- [Hulu](http://kodi.wiki/view/Hulu)
- [YouTube](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:YouTube)
- [Xbox controller](http://kodi.wiki/view/Xbox_360_Wireless_Controller) (I use a remote keyboard such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ALQL9I0))
- [Steam Launcher](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=157499)

There is no integrated web browser, but here is a link to the [unofficial add-ons index](http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/OpenELEC_Add-ons_(Unofficial)) where you can install a variety of third perty add-ons, including Opera Web Browser

Comment: No, I'd keep this as an answer. While it is XBMC, it's a different platform. Looks cool!

Comment: Problem though: OpenELEC and EFI do ***not*** like each other.

Comment: @Mew Reading through the forums shows that a few people managed to make it work by compiling it from the source. But you're right, it doesn't seem straightforward. Maybe running it from a USB stick is easier?

Comment: I'll just see if I can build my own using Xubuntu. Thanks for the links. They really came in handy. +10 rep to you.